# Markov decision processes: action set revealed at point of decision

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I have a problem which looks like a finite horizon Markov decision process (MDP), except the action space at each time is revealed at the decision making point. There is no way to know before hand the action space for the $\{0,1,\dots,T\}$ epochs.

So I feel that backward induction ([principal of optimality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman_equation)) cannot be applied here as actions at those end epochs are not known.

Is there any theory built for such cases? Please help me understand how I should change the existing theory of Markov decision processes to this case or a reference will do. Even a keyword to search for will go a long way. Thanks.

Edit:

It is possible that the super-set $A$, of all actions is know to the decision maker at time time $0$, so that $A_t \subset A $, where $A_t$ is the actions space at time $t$. The decision maker knows $A_0$ and $A$ at the beginning of the decision process but does not know $A_t$ for $1 \leq t \leq T$ till the time arrives.

In my problem it is not causal to assume a prior distributions for $A_t$s. I guess if one assumes a distribution for each $A_t$ then this problem boils down to a MDP.

PS: I asked [this question in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/819474/markov-decision-processes-with-action-space-only-revealed-at-point-of-decision) but didn't receive an answer yet so decided to post here.

Comment: Welcome to MO! Nice question, but next time maybe you should wait a bit more than a day to cross-post here.

Comment: Is there any chance for a theory here? I mean, you come to a strange place and are offered to play a game where at every point you are asked if you want to stop or to continue. If you stop, the game ends and you keep everything you have won up to that point. If you choose to continue, during the first $n$ moves, they just give you 1000 dollars each time, but during the $n+1$st move, they take all money back and chop your head off. You are told all rules here except a single parameter $n\ge 0$ that is not revealed to you, but I doubt you can talk about "an optimal strategy" or anything...

Comment: @fedja Suppose we know the super set from which the subset of actions are revealed at each stage. Such that $A_t \subset A$, where $A_t$ is the action set of time $t$. The decision maker knows $A$ and $A_0$ at time $0$, like wise at time $t$ he knows $A$ and $A_t$. Do we stand a chance then? Thanks a lot for the comment